# Automatically updating a userform label

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm new to VBA and programming in general, so bear with me. I have so far 6 labels, and a simple useform where one enters a value corresponding to each label. However, the label name can change (say if new labels are added) and I wanted a way to automatically change the label name. This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Update_invest.Invest1.Caption = Sheet1.Range("A12").Value
Update_invest.Invest2.Caption = Sheet1.Range("A13").Value
Update_invest.Invest3.Caption = Sheet1.Range("A14").Value
Update_invest.Invest4.Caption = Sheet1.Range("A15").Value
Update_invest.Invest5.Caption = Sheet1.Range("A16").Value
Update_invest.Invest6.Caption = Sheet1.Range("A17").Value

End Sub
```

Now this works: if I change a label it will update the userform. However, if I just open the new worksheet and don't click on say cell A12, it will not update the userform and will leave the label name as it's default name. How do I make it actually save the label name, so that if a user opens the workbook the userform will already have the current cell value (without first having to click on the cell for the userform to update)?

I have this code currently on sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

You can put your code in `Worksheet_Activate` which is run when the user select the sheet or in `Workbook_Open` which is run when the user open the workbook. Currently, your are using `Worksheet_SelectionChange` which is only run when the user change the selection, hence the need to click on another cell.

**NOTE :** if you chose to use `Workbook_Open`, you will need to put the sub in the `ThisWorkbook` file and not in the worksheet itself.

### Solution 2

If you instead want to make the changes permanant and not have code to always update it, you will need to go through the [designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264339.aspx)

Here is an exemple

```
Sub exa1()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    n = 12
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Update_invest").Designer
        For i = 1 To .Controls.Count
            If TypeName(.Controls(i - 1)) = "Label" Then           
                .Controls(i - 1).Caption = Sheet1.Cells(n, 1).Value
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[source](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/582048-permanently-change-userform-label-captions-through-visual-basic-applications.html)

Comment: Thanks, that does work in the sense that if they open the file they will be able to see whats currently there, however it still does not actually update the label name. I just tested it using workbook_open, and it worked fine whilst opening the workbook but if I go back onto the vba code, or rerun the userform it will have whatever label it had beforehand. Is there a way to permanently save whatever it updates to?

Comment: @user33484 Updated answer

Comment: just saw, thanks for that. I think that's a little beyond me right now, but just taking a look at the code are you using the loops to cycle through each of the labels? I was looking at a way of doing that instead of typing repeatedly invest1, invest 2 etc and named them because I wanted to create a for loop for it but had no idea how

Comment: Also, where would I put this sub procedure? Could I create a new module for it, and would every other module etc be able to call it?

Comment: @user33484 yes, that code (which is not mine BTW) loops through all the controls of the forms and then only modify the one's that are labels.

Comment: @user33484 You can put it anywhere you want. however, it need to be mannually run (with F5) or be called from an event